# Converting gamepad thumbstick values to range

Tags: c++, input, directx, xinput, gamepad

I'm trying to get the value from the thumbstick with XInput, but the values are weird and I don't know how to handle them correctly.

How do I calculate so that I can read the values between -1 (thumbstick to the left/up) +1 (thumbstick to the right/down)

Similiar to XNA's Gamepad.GetState().ThumbSticks.Left.X ( -1 = to the left, +1 = to the right ).

Any ideas?

Comment: Show what code you've written that produces the "weird" values.

Comment: float x = (float)ThumbstickLeftX / (float)32768 becomes values like = 1072693184 and such.. if I remove (float) I get nothing.

Comment: Can it be because the deadzone is to high or something?

Comment: Show your conversion code with sample input values and the resulting output values.  You can edit your original question.  Just tack this info on at the end.

Comment: What are your maximum & minimum unconverted (raw) values for ThumbstickLeftX?

Comment: They're between - 32768 to 32768, but it was just a weird calculation error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.xinput_gamepad%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `_XINPUT_GAMEPAD.sThumbLX` is a `SHORT` whose value lies between -32768 and 32767. If you want to convert that to a range of [-1, 1), divide the value by 32768.0.

Comment: No, that'll produce a guaranteed value of zero due to integer division.  Divide by 32768.0 intstead.

Comment: @phonetagger, good catch on the integer division problem. edited.

Comment: I had some odd results first with this, but I guess it was a simple calculation failure that resultet in weird numbers cause I got a ten digit from calculating those without a delimiter...